# Laravel Webpack mix.js Cannot Compile with extenstion .vue

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js

I'm new to webpack in Laravel. I already managed to compile the default scripts into one. However, when I tried to add a new Vue Controller in a separate folder, it seems it will not be included during npm run dev.

Currently I have this set-up

```
-assets
 --js
 ---app.js
 ---test.vue


    mix.js([
        'resources/assets/js/app.js',
        'resources/assets/js/test.vue'
    ], 'public/js/app.js');
```

This will work. However when I put test.vue inside a folder.

```
-assets
     --js
     ---app.js
     --controllers
     --test.vue


        mix.js([
            'resources/assets/js/app.js',
            'resources/assets/js/controllers/test.vue'
        ], 'public/js/app.js');
```

However, when I changed it from test.vue to test.js it will compile. Does the file extension matter? when compiling mix.js?

Can someone help me out on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken you can't compile single .vue files using webpack without some sort of loader

Using Vue.component() and importing a vue file into a .js file and then compiling the .js will work.

This might be of help: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader

> Vue Single-File Component (SFC) Spec
> A *.vue file is a custom file format that uses HTML-like syntax to
> describe a Vue component. Each *.vue file consists of three types of
> top-level language blocks: , , and , and
> optionally additional custom blocks:
>
> vue-loader will parse the file, extract each language block, pipe them
> through other loaders if necessary, and finally assemble them back
> into an ES Module whose default export is a Vue.js component options
> object.

Comment: I never heard of that @Marcus